# Auth0 Access Token Not Returning Roles (Authorization Extension)

Tags: angular, .net-core, auth0

Please assist. I am very new in Auth0. I want to use Role Based Access Control (RBAC) in my angular 8 app and ASP.NET Core 2.2 API. I have registered both the API and SPA in Auth0. The **authentication is working fine** but I am having issues with authorization. The access_token that I am getting back from Auth0 does not have the roles in it. It has the permissions instead of the roles. I have installed Auth0 Authorization2.6 extension. I have also enabled RBAC. 
I get this from the output log (Visual Studio 2019) `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer.JwtBearerHandler:Information: Successfully validated the token.` And it fails to authorize with this error `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.DefaultAuthorizationService:Information: Authorization failed`

I have created users, roles and permissions. I assigned all my users the relevant roles. Below is the code snippet from my Startup class (the API).

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2);

        services.AddCors(options =>
        {
            options.AddPolicy("AllowSpecificOrigin",
                builder =>
                {
                    builder
                    .WithOrigins("http://localhost:4200")
                    .AllowAnyMethod()
                    .AllowAnyHeader()
                    .AllowCredentials();
                });
        });


        var domain = $"https://{Configuration["Auth0:Issuer"]}/";

        services.AddAuthentication(options =>
        {
            options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            options.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        }).AddJwtBearer(options =>
        {
            options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
            {
                NameClaimType = ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier,
                RoleClaimType = ClaimTypes.Role,
                ValidateIssuer = true,
                ValidateAudience = true,
                ValidateLifetime = true,
                ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                ValidIssuer = Configuration["Auth0:Issuer"],
                ValidAudience = Configuration["Auth0:Audience"],
                IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Configuration.GetSection("Auth0")["ClientSecret"]))
            };
            options.Authority = domain;
            options.Audience = Configuration["Auth0:Audience"];
        });

        services.AddAuthorization(options =>
        {
            options.AddPolicy("StakeholderManager", policy => policy.RequireRole("StakeholderManager"));
        });
    }
```

My API endpoint looks like this

```
[HttpGet("students")]
[Authorize(Roles = "StakeholderManager")]
    public IActionResult GetAllStudents()
    {
        var user = User;
        return Ok(new
        {
            Student1 = "James Bond",
            Student2 = "Belinda Abrahams"
        });
    }
```

Below if my access token that is sent to the API for authentication and authorization

[image]

Enabled RBAC

[image]

I have also modified the Auth0 Authorization rule to try and include the roles as per screenshot below, but this did not help either.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The authorization extension will be deprecated and replaced by the core RBAC feature (this is the roles you see in the user section of the dashboard). If you migrate your roles and permission to that feature, you should be able to add the roles to the token in a custom claim like you have tried to do in the screenshot you provided.

See this doc for an example:
https://auth0.com/docs/authorization/concepts/sample-use-cases-rules#add-user-roles-to-tokens

This doc is also useful:
https://auth0.com/docs/authorization/concepts/core-vs-extension